# How to split string in 2 word string set in c#

Tags: c#

I have a string in c#. I want to split that string into 2 words string sets like:

```
string str = "Split handles splitting upon string and character delimiters."
```

Output should be:

```
1: "Split handles"
2: "splitting upon"
3: "string and"
4: "character delimiters."
```

What should be the best method to do this?

**Here is what i have tried yet:**

```
    private List<string> Spilt(string text)
    {
        List<string> bunch = new List<string>();
        int block = 15;
        string[] words = text.Split(' ');
        int length = words.Length;
        int remain = 0;

        while(remain < length)
        {
            bunch.Add(string.Join(" ", words.Take(block)));
            remain += block;
        }

        return bunch;
    }
```

Comment: You could count spaces, if 2 then capture 2 words.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest approach would be to split at each space, and then "re-join" the pairs back, like this:

```
var pairs = str.Split(' ')
    .Select((s,i) => new {s, i})
    .GroupBy(n => n.i / 2)
    .Select(g => string.Join(" ", g.Select(p=>p.s)))
    .ToList();
```

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/XUwPsG)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
        string str = "Split handles splitting upon string and character delimiters.";
        var strnew = str.Split(' ');
        var strRes = string.Empty;
        int j = 1; 
        for (int i = 0; i < strnew.Length; i=i+2)
        {
            strRes += j.ToString()+": " + @"""" + strnew[i] + " " + strnew[i+1] + @"""" +"\n" ;
            j++; 
        }
        Console.Write(strRes); 
        // print strRes
```